# Eclipse - PHP Include Path

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt

I´m working with Eclipse 3.4.2 with PDT.
I´ve added some libraries in the applications folder, and add that folder to the PHP Include Path.

When I run as script, it works perfect, but if I access the page outside eclipse, the libraries are not accesible, i need to add this line:

set_include_path(
 implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(realpath('../application'),  get_include_path(),))
);

Is this necesary? how can avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also specify path in [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statement, but it's not very convenient.

Also, you may specify corresponding include_path value in php.ini configuration file (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) for details), but usually this directive contains path to system-wide libraries, not application-specific paths.

If you are using OOP, you may implement your own class-loader, which will look for classes in specific directories. See [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is necessary. Because PHP interpreter should know, from what folders load libraries.